# How to design a pub/sub architecture for real-time stock price

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-pulsar

I have an external system that publish real-time financial data(e.g. stock quote and price from exchange all over the world).

This external system has some limitation on number of stocks per account connection, as we have many applications need to consume these real-time streaming data so we don't want each application to connect to that external system and manage the capacity by themselves, hence we want to design a single system that do the consumption for all stocks and then publish to some message queue(e.g. kafka or pulsar), then the downstream application can consume from the kafka topics.

The problem is how we can design the topics, the number of stocks is around 10 millions, but each application is only interest in subset of them, the subset size can either be small or large, and different subset could share the same stocks.

What I can think is to dynamically create some streaming job(e.g. kafka streaming or a separate flink job to do a pre-aggregation to collect the interested stocks for each consumer from all topics and then publish to another topic for each consumer), in this way each consumer will have its own topic with only its interested stocks, but will definitely bring the overhead of message transportation time, duplicate message, and latency, besides that, the capacity might also be a problem if there are more and more consumers.

I don't know if there are any better way to achieve my requirements, please advice, thank you.

Comment: Is Kafka a hard requirement? Complex routing scenarios are easier to model with AMQP.

Comment: No, not necessary to be Kafka, I will check on RabbitMQ, thanks.

Comment: The routing function in RabbitMQ seems fit my basic requirement, I can assign a new queue to a new consumer dynamically to publish the consumer's interested data. However, I have some concern about the message rate limit on one exchange and one queue, do I have to put all messages to one exchange and then route them to different queues? We can't bind a queue to multiple exchanges, right?

Comment: Pulsar is supposed to solve both problems, the scalability of Kafka with the routing features similar to AMQP. I've never used it personally, but that's probably where I would start if I was you.

Comment: I actually looked at Pulsar before, but seems the routing function is not good enough, may have to use Pulsar function to implement my requirement?

Comment: Hi, wonder how you solved this problem. Also, what do you do regarding slow consumers - for example - you want to keep the latest bid value for a specific contract.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you have some real-time feed of stock prices which includes quotes for ALL securities on that exchange, i.e. APPL, IBM, and MSFT quotes are included in that single feed. Also, you don't want consumers directly attaching to this feed, so you need to store that information in an intermediate message system

In that case you may want to consider using Pulsar's [key_shared subscription](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/#key_shared) to pre-sort the data by ticker symbol. Each of these consumers could then publish their results to a ticker symbol specific topic.  Clients would then need to subscribe to only those topics that they are interested in and consume a subset of that data.

All ticker symbols ----> (500 symbol-specific topics). <---- Client subscribes to subset of these.

Comment: Just trying to understand the volume of these data exchanges, what could be the approx. size of one update/message, If all securities from an exchange are included in a single feed? and how frequent this update happens in real-time in general, may be if we talk about NYSE?  I saw there are NYSE real time feeds listed on their site. But just kind of trying to understand in terms of system-design perspective.

Comment: That would depend on the data provider, i.e the NYSE. However, it would make the most sense to have one feed providing quotes for ALL stocks where each message would contain two pieces of information: the ticker symbol and the quoted price. If we were to use the ticker symbol as the message key, then with Pulsar Key-shared subscription, then the data would be pre-sorted for us, i.e. all the APPL quotes would go to the same consumer.